# Last Instance of Character

Tags: string, swift, indexing, substring

I'm looking to find the last instance of a character in a string. Given the different way Swift deals with strings (ranges), I was hoping someone has run into this before as I can't seem to figure out the best way to deal with it.

The string I'd like to parse is similar to "http://imanimage_thatlooks_likethis_andmypixare_380.jpg". I need to parse the segment between the last "_" and the last ".". So the number 380. Each link is formatted this way, but the substring methodology for Swift is still a bit foreign to me, with the inclusion of different byte lengths.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// regular expression to find substring between last "_" and last "."
let sourceStr = "abc_defg_hijk_lmn.xyz"
let regex = NSRegularExpression( pattern: "_([^_]*)\\.[^\\.]*$", options:nil, error:nil );
if let matchingResult = regex?.firstMatchInString( sourceStr, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange( 0, countElements( sourceStr ) ) ) {
    let matchingRange = matchingResult.rangeAtIndex(1)
    let matchingString = (sourceStr as NSString).substringWithRange( matchingRange )
}
```

Comment: Using the above, I can get an NSRange, but when attempting to use that in this fashion myString.substringWithRange(matchingRange) it says a string.index must be used, not an NSRange.

Comment: Okay, I added a line to get the substring.

Comment: That seems to work. Is there any potential issues with converting a swift string object working off of String.index into an NSString?

Comment: I don't know if there are any issues. Apple's "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" iBook states: “Swift automatically bridges between the String type and the NSString class. This means that anywhere you use an NSString object, you can use a Swift String type instead and gain the benefits of both types—the String type’s interpolation and Swift-designed APIs and the NSString class’s broad functionality. ”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/1u3-0.l